# Google App Engine - run docker image with specific Linux version

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, dockerfile, instance, asp.net-core-3.1

I a new one in Google App Engine and trying to deploy my ASP.Net Core 3.1 Blazor web site to Google App Engine. I use a custom build with Docker, because the App Engine hasn't supportted .Net Core 3.1 yet:

**App.yaml**

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

**Dockerfile** # Generated by Visual Studio

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.3-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.201-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Blazor_SqLite_Publish/Blazor_SqLite_Publish.csproj", "Blazor_SqLite_Publish/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Blazor_SqLite_Publish/Blazor_SqLite_Publish.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Blazor_SqLite_Publish"
RUN dotnet build "Blazor_SqLite_Publish.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Blazor_SqLite_Publish.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blazor_SqLite_Publish.dll"]
```

The Web site is deployed successfully and even works. But I noticed, that App Engine instance runs my docker image on Ubuntu-16.04.6 LTS:

```
root@xxxxxxxxxxx:/app# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
```

But I expect Ubuntu-18.04 LTS.

**How can change Ubuntu-16.04.6 LTS version to Ubuntu-18.04 LTS?**

Comment: My instance is running with the Ubuntu 18.04. I copied your Dockerfile, changed to use the Hello World [code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart). And changed the runtime to 3.1 on the HelloWorld.csproj. And updated the HelloWord yaml to custom.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue. Thanks breddy, that checked my Dockerfile.

My Dockerfile was located in solution folder, not in project. As result Visual Studio generated temporar Dockerfile each time I published my web site to GAE. The generated Dockerfile contained gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1 image:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blazor_SqLite_Publish.dll"]
```

That is why, my docker image was based on Ubuntu-16.04 LTS.